# Как передать внешней библиотеке строку в другой кодировке?

Tags: c#, кодировка, текст

Функция во внешней библиотеке может принимать только текст в кодировке 1251. Строки в c# хранятся в Unicode, это известно.

```
bytes[] textIn1251 = (Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)).GetBytes(text1);
```

Т.е. я получаю массив байтов текста в кодировке 1251. Но я не могу передать их вместо строки в эту внешнюю функцию

И вот в этот момент я не понимаю что происходит:
Если я сделаю так:

```
string test = e1251.GetString(Encoding.Convert(uni, e1251, uni.GetBytes(textInUNI)));
```

то я снова получу test в Unicode (верно ведь?), и не смогу его успешно передать в внешнюю функцию.

Как в данном случае можно поступить?

Comment: _внешняя библиотека принимает текст в кодировке 1251_, внешняя библиотека что из себя представляет? на каком языке она написана? Как вы хотите ее вызвать? добавьте пжлста описание внешней бибилотеке

Comment: Верно: строки в .NET имеют кодировку Unicode (UTF-16). В общем случае, нужно получить массив байтов в нужной кодировке (1251) и этот массив байтов передать библиотеке. Но сперва ответьте на вопросы Алексея.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov библиотека для анализа текста. Нужная функция принимает (string text, ref base rezult), т.е. текст анализирует, и возвращает новый элемент собственного класса base. Перегрузки типа (byte[] textByte, ref base rezult) нет. Язык vb/c/c++ (не могу сказать точно, код библиотеки неуправляемый)

Comment: Если неуправляемый, то вероятно С++. 
в принципе @AlexanderPetrov ответил на ваш вопрос. Передаете массива байт(полученную при преобразовании строки win1251) в неуправляемый код https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21651229/passing-byte-array-to-pinvoke-call-changes-it-to-null, а в нем уже имея массив char-ов рулите.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov Спасибо за ответ. Но к сожалению боюсь это (дополнение неуправляемого кода) пока за пределами моих способностей или понимания. В теме что вы прикрепили ошибка рода типов параметров, и вроде бы оно не очень связано с этой проблемой

Comment: @ОльгаОмельчишина указанный пример может не совсем хороший, но я его ответ показывает, каким образом передать массив байт в управляемый код.